# Adding Python installation for an Electron app

Tags: python, node-modules, electron-packager, squirrel.windows

I am creating an Eletron desktop application for Windows. I am using `electron-packager` and then `electron-squirrel-startup` to create an .exe file. Like in this tutorial:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/365/how-to-create-a-windows-installer-for-an-application-built-with-electron-framework

I would like to add installation of Python to the installer. Does anyone know how to do it?

My guess is somewhere here in main.js file:

```
function handleSquirrelEvent(application) {    
    switch (squirrelEvent) {
        case '--squirrel-install':
        case '--squirrel-updated':
        //HERE
```

but I'm not sure.

Edit:

My idea was to use `node-cmd` module to execute Windows `cmd` commands, yet for some reason code like this

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');
cmd.run('touch example.txt');
```

does not work in the `handleSquirrelEvent` function. It works outside of it though.